# tikzcd in 2.1 and 3.0

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

If I have a code written in 2.1 pgf version for tikz-cd and I install the 3.0 version, I could compile that code?

I know some syntaxis has change, but maybe the latest version accept both.

Comment: `tikz-cd` is also updated after TikZ v3.0 released. But you can never know without trying your code. Install on a different computer or try online LaTeX sites. Because it is a temporal thing and this site is a bit about more general questions I'm afraid.

Comment: @percusse I think that if the question owner showed a specific 2.10 code that doesn't work in 3.0, it would be fine as a question.

Comment: @yo' which would defeat the purpose of the question as a counterexample no?

Comment: @user Make a backup and try it. I had never problems with the most recent updates. Everything stayed compatible as far as I can see.